# ntp reference clock driver don't work properly

Tags: ntp

My company have a project that ntp involved. That needs build a stratum 1 server based on FPGA hardware that acts as reference clock.  So I followed the ntp website How to write a reference clock ,wrote a reference clock driver and put it in the .../ntpd/ directory,and modified the related files ,such as, /include/ntp.h,/libntp/clocktypes.c,Makefile.am etc.When complete that,I compiled successfully.

In my /etc/ntp.conf:
    server 127.127.47.0

but when I executed sudo ntpd and ntpq -p ,the terminal outputs:

No association ID's returned

My question is how to make my own driver work properly .When I tried out server 127.127.46.0,but I got the same No association Id...I think it'not my driver's problem.

I can't figure out that and now I'm stuck on ,please help,thanks!